# Card-Columns Boostrap como renderizar de forma horizontal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

he implementado una matriz con [cards-columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-columns) pero estas son renderizadas por columnas

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

como podria renderizarlas por filas asi

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

estoy creando la matriz con angular asi

```
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of peliculas.results">
      <div class="containerimg">
    <img [src]="item.poster_path | domseguro:'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300'" class="card-img-top img-thumbnail img-fluid image" alt="{{item.title}}">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="text"><strong class="font-italic">Popularidad:</strong> {{item.popularity | number:'2.0-0'}}</div>
        <div class="text"><strong class="font-italic">Votos:</strong> {{item.vote_count | number:'2.0-0'}}</div>
        <img src="https://www.shareicon.net/download/2016/01/30/711363_cinema_512x512.png" alt="no adult" style="width:50px" *ngIf="item.adult">
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{item.title}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{item.overview | cutResume}}</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Lanzamiento: {{item.release_date}}</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Esto me genera una matriz de 3 columnas siempre, pero no organizadas de forma horizontal o por filas, peliculas.result es un array

[preview](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjtpbg)

Comment: Hola Alejandro, vamos a necesitar algo más de información (y a ser posible de código) para ver qué es lo que está fallando. Por favor, lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta para añadir uno. Saludos.

Comment: Ya que estas utilizando Angular, seria bueno que incluyeras un enlace a Stackblitz o sitios similares para que la gente pueda probar tu codigo

Comment: Hola amigos, ya subi el ejemplo